# CSS way to change the content of an element on classList.toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a CSS way to change the content of an element on classList.toggle ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#so.collapsed
{
    content: "SO";
    border:1px solid red;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="so">StackOverflow</div>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>

    <script>
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () =>
    {    
        document.getElementById('so').classList.toggle("collapsed");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

One solution is :

```
#so:before
{
    content: "StackOverflow";
}
#so.collapsed:before
{
    content: "SO";
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

But I was hoping to have the content in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

CSS content can only be used with pseudo elements `after` or `before`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#so.collapsed:before
{
    content: "SO";
    border:1px solid red;
}
#so.collapsed span {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="so"><span>StackOverflow</span></div>
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>

    <script>
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () =>
    {    
        document.getElementById('so').classList.toggle("collapsed");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want StackOverflow replaced with SO

Comment: @anjanesh In order to get the desired result, you can wrap the "Stack Overflow" text in `span` and toggle its `display` property. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I was hoping to look for a solution that changes just the #so content : `#so.collapsed`

Comment: That seems to be possible only using JS